# How can I simulate my Apple Watch app? - Xcode 6.3

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode6.3

I updated to Xcode 6.3 and can't find the Hardware < External Display < etc. to access the Apple watch simulator.

It seems like Hardware was replaced by 'Product' but I still can't find the 'External Display'.

Answer (score 3):

You can find Hardware < External Display < etc. at simulator's menu

[image]

Comment: I updated Xcode to 6.3 and added a screenshot for you.

Comment: @Python_is_cool Make sure you choose a device that supports pairing with the watch.  Select an iPhone 6s simulator rather than an iPhone 4s simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened and chosen "iOS Simulator" application?
As you mention before, about item "Product", I can understand, that you could confused Xcode menu with iOS Simulator menu. There is no such menu item "Product" in iOS Simulator. Look at pics below.

This is Xcode application menu.
[image: Xcode app menu]

This is iOS Simulator application menu.
[image: iOS Simulator menu]